# TWIG: Get the first item fulfilling a condition

Tags: twig

I need to display the first item that fulfills some condition. Something I would normally do via construction like this pseudocode:

```
for(item in some_array)
  if(some_condition(item)) {
    some_action();
    break;
  }
```

The problem is I need to do that in TWIG and TWIG does not allow to break a for loop. How to do that then?

Comment: Consider locating the item in your controller or write a twig filter/function to do this

Answer (score 1):

You could use a boolean to denote that you have processed the first item but it will continue to loop over the rest of the array:

```
set firstItemProcessed = false;
for(item in some_array) {
    if(firstItemProcessed == false and some_condition(item) ) {
       some_action();
       firstItemProcessed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the way to go but then in twig syntax ofc ^^